# REBOL3 - How to copy binary from binary! to block! properly

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm trying to copy binary data to an array, and I'm getting a result I don't expect.  I reduced it to this smaller problem that demonstrates it.

```
b: #{0102030405060708}
c: array (length? b)
repeat num (length? b) [
    print [
        {Setting location}
        num
        {to value of}
        to-binary reduce [(pick b num)]
    ] 
    poke c num (to-binary reduce [(pick b num)]) 
]
```

This results in:

```
Setting location 1 to value of #{01}
Setting location 2 to value of #{02}
Setting location 3 to value of #{03}
Setting location 4 to value of #{04}
Setting location 5 to value of #{05}
Setting location 6 to value of #{06}
Setting location 7 to value of #{07}
Setting location 8 to value of #{08}
== #{08}

>> c
== [#{08} #{08} #{08} #{08} #{08} #{08} #{08} #{08}]
```

I can see that I am returning the `==#{08}` with my repeat block, but I don't konw where that is coming from.  I checked with `trace on` and it seems that the poke statement is setting all elements of the block at every step of the repeat.  This seems to be a pointer issue and I can resolve it with `copy`.  Can someone give me an idea of what is happening?

Some more tests:

```
>> to-binary reduce [pick b 1]
== #{01}

>> poke c 1 to-binary reduce [pick b 1]
== #{01}

>> c
== [#{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01}]

>> poke c 2 #{02}
== #{02}

>> c
== [#{01} #{02} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01} #{01}]

>> u: to-binary reduce [pick b 4]
== #{04}

>> poke c 4 u
== #{04}

>> c
== [#{04} #{02} #{04} #{04} #{04} #{04} #{04} #{04}]
```

Response to Ladislavs answer:

Thank you for the answer about the bug.

The first example gives a different result than what I am expecting. The binary elements are each of 8 length, whereas I was interested in length 1 (hence the use of the block argument to `to-binary`. )

```
>> c
== [#{0000000000000001} #{0000000000000002} #{0000000000000003} #{0000000000000004} #{0000000000000005} #{0000000000000006} #{0000000000000007} #{0000000000000008}]
```

The second works, by replacing `c: array (length? b)` with `c: copy []`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You encountered a known bug. (the correcting pull request has already been submitted, AFAIK) The workaround is to never use a block as an argument of the to-binary function. The following code should work:

```
b: #{0102030405060708}
c: array (length? b)
repeat num (length? b) [
    print [
        {Setting location}
        num
        {to value of}
        to-binary pick b num
    ] 
    poke c num to-binary pick b num 
]
```

However, the whole code looks overcomplicated to me, and I would rather achieve your goal using:

```
b: #{0102030405060708}
c: make block! length? b
repeat num (length? b) [
    print [
        {Setting location}
        num
        {to value of}
        copy/part at b num 1
    ]
    append c copy/part at b num 1
]
```

If you want just to create a short (length 1) binary from an integer, you may use this formula:

```
append copy #{} 255
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Ladislav.  Regarding the 1st of your examples, is there a different way to create binary of length shorter than 8?  I edited my answer above with a response.

Granted, I will adjust to using `append`, but I was just curious.